# Как получить промежуточный код компиляции при использовании шаблонов?

Tags: gcc

Для препроцессора есть аргумент компилятора `-E`, для получения ассемблерного кода есть аргумент `-S`, а вот для получения кода инстанцированных шаблонных функций я не нашёл.

...

Для себя я нашёл ответ: Нужен аргумент `-fdump-tree-original`
Но этот ответ отвергли "модераторы", поэтому пишу в вопросе.

Comment: А в каком-нибудь из файлов, полученных при помощи -fdump-rtl-all есть такое же содержимое, как генерирует -fdump-rtl-expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужен аргумент `-fdump-tree-original`